# Parsing parameters to main()

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

In C++, is there a well done, complete, open source implementation of a utility to parse the parameters of the main() function?

I wrote my own, and I saw many others around. But I was wandering if there is a better implementation available, which provides all the features expected from the corresponding executable.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- getopt
- [boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html)
- Poco OptionSet/[OptionProcessor](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.OptionProcessor.html)

Answer (score 5):

Boost provides an open-source implementation with [ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this framework:
[CmdLine: a C++ option-parsing framework](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/ftp/src/libs/C++/CmdLine.html)